# Plotly showing unnecessary space in heat map

Tags: python, plotly-python

I am trying to create a heatmap.
The code:

```
import plotly.express as px                 

fig = px.imshow(data.corr().values)              
fig.update_layout(               
    title="Correlation matrix",            
    xaxis_title="X",             
    yaxis_title="Y",                
    coloraxis_colorbar=dict(             
        title="Your Title",             
    ))               
fig.show()
```

The plot:
[image: Correlation matrix]

Comment: And what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the size of your Figure explicitly to remove this white space if you don't want it. For example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

data = np.random.randn(10, 10)
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig = px.imshow(data.corr().values)
fig.update_layout(
    title="Correlation matrix",
    xaxis_title="X",
    yaxis_title="Y",
    coloraxis_colorbar=dict(
        title="Your Title"),
    width = 700, height = 700,
    autosize = False)
fig.show()
```

produces[image: correlation matrix without white space]

Comment: Thank you so much! It works like a charm. :)

Comment: Is it possible to still have a heatmap that adjust to the page size but without the white space ?